# xamarin.forms - pass viewModel data to android activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am making an `OnKeyDown` and Up for volume buttons event. If app detect both of them clicked then it should move to another Page. Thing is I want to pass `BindingContext` to new page.

Overall it is in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Add(Keycode.VolumeUp);
                if (_pressedKeys.Contains(Keycode.VolumeDown))
                {
                    ChangePage(); //go to view
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Add(Keycode.VolumeUp);
                if (_pressedKeys.Contains(Keycode.VolumeUp))
                {

                    ChangePage(); ////go to view
                }
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
        }
```

Overall function is working and its nice. Problem is because I dont know how pass `BindingContext`. I tried to do something like this:

```
var mainViewModel = Application.Current.MainPage.BindingContext as MainViewModel;
```

But `Application` not contain a definition for `Current`...

I am still learning xamarin.forms and struggling with this from few hours... Could you help me guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use:

```
var mainViewModel = App.Current.MainPage.BindingContext as MainViewModel;
```

Check your App class name(in PCL library). This should work.